Rename multiple files with a variable number via loop in batch
I have a couple of files, let's say numbered 40, with extensions .htm, .html, .mhtml etc- (not the same - it's important). Here's a brief example:
alpha.htm
beta.htm
gamma.html
delta.htm

I would like to rename them all using one pattern, in this manner:
alpha.htm → 0.htm
beta.htm → 1.htm
gamma.html → 2.htm
delta.htm → 3.htm

Unfortunately, it would be inappropriate to create the plain ren file with instructions like above, since all the .htms appear to be welded to their related content folders, and Windows blocks any tryouts to rename them this way. Although, it suddenly works for loops.
So I would like to use loop, and the function taking two arguments - the first one for name and the second one - for the number to be used as counter:
SET %num%=0
FOR %%I in (*.*ht*) DO Call :_deactivate "%%~nxI %num%"
:_deactivate
Ren "%~1" "%~2%~x1"
Set /A "%~2+=1"

Seems to be that interpreter does not really know how to read this "%~2%~x1", which is really a combination of the second argument (%~2) and an extension of filename from the first argument (%~x1), and I don't really know if it is possible to combine these variables there ever, and how is this done.
SET /A %%\~2+=1 complains about the absence of operand, so I think it doesn't really see two operands here.
I searched around to find the correct form to combine custom variables with Batch internal wildcards for files;
I tried to rewrite %num% as %%z, to use delayed expansion mode with !num! exclamation marks notation. Didn't work. I'm out of ideas, even how to search it correctly.

Your problem is here Set /A "%~2+=1", which would resolve to Set /A "0+=1", Set /A "0+=1", Set /A "0+=1" etc. Perhaps you meant to use Set /A "num=%~2+1" instead. Although Set /A num+=1 would probably have sufficed.

Try SET /A num=0 & Call :_deactivate "%%~nxI" num". The set command you have used attempts to set the variable the contents of num. The revised call delivers the name&extension of file "%%I" & the string num to the subroutine :_deactivate. Your version would deliver ONE parameter - %%~nxI ? where ? is the value of num as it stood when the for was originally encountered.

Batch has no concept of "sections", "functions", "procedures" or "paragraphs". A label is simply a reference point. Execution does not stop when a label is reached, it simply continues through, line by line, until it reaches end-of-file, a CALL , a GOTO or an EXIT. Hence you need goto :eof before the label :_deactivate else the code of :_deactivate will be executed when the for loop is ended.

It's normal to follow an initial @echo off with a setlocal as any statements executed before the setlocal are retained in the environment after the batch ends, which can cause confusion for subsequent batches as the variables use may be unexpectedly set.

Note that the for structure you have used is aimed at each .htm* file in turn. However, if you rename a file, it may be reprocessed with its new name This is particularly the case for FAT volumes. Use `for /f "delims=" %%I in ('dir /b /a-d *.ht') instead, which builds a filename list in memory first, then processes that list (many articles on SO about this)

@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET num=0
FOR %%I in (*.*ht*) DO Call :_deactivate "%%~nxI" %%~xI !num!
goto :eof
pause

:_deactivate
Ren "%~1" "%~3%~2"
Set /A num+=1


Num does not write the symbol % for variable names.
Use goto :eof above the label because you need to get out after the For statement.
Use a total of three arguments to pass the extension arguments to the label.
To use the delayed extension variable, define the extension variable at the top and group the num variable with !.
%~2 is not the name of the num variable.

